# Text centered below ion-avatar inside ion-grid

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i would like to achieve this result :

[image]

currently this is what i use to achieve this :

```
<ion-row no-padding align-items-center>
  <ion-col col-4>
    <ion-item class="avatars nobackground" icon-start no-lines text-left> . 
      <ion-icon name="stopwatch"></ion-icon>
      1h
     </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-8>
    <ion-item no-lines text-left>
      <ion-avatar text-center>
        <img [src]="workout.coach?.image_name" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <span>{{ workout.coach?.firstname }} {{ workout.coach?.lastname }}</span>
     </ion-item>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

This gives me this :

[image]

As you can see the text isn't centered below the ion-avatar i've tested `text-center` property in `ion-item` containing the text and the ion-avatar but this doesn't seem to work...

By the way if you also have a suggestion to have the `ion-col` perfectly centered i will take it aswell.

Edit 1:

Thanks to @Phonolog i've managed to get it centered perfectly, now if someone as a suggestion to reduce first `ion-row` height to match first picture perfectly it would be great <3, i've tried to modify height property with no success. (I'm the worst front-end developper).

Regards,
Thomas.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, maybe you can use 3 rows instead of fidgetting with the col attributes? One for left-aligned with stopwatch, one centered with the icon and the last centered with the text.

Comment: See @Phonolog's comment for more input, that's what he suggested aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a second row and setting the imgs display to inline? See this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9eqkht). Inline styles used for brevity...

```
<ion-row no-padding align-items-center>
    <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="avatars nobackground" icon-start no-lines text-left>
            <ion-icon name="stopwatch"></ion-icon>1h
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>
        <ion-item no-lines text-center>
            <ion-avatar text-center>
                <img [src]="workout.coach?.image_name" style="display: inline;"/>
            </ion-avatar>
            <span>{{ workout.coach?.firstname }} {{ workout.coach?.lastname }}</span>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

If you want to get even closer to your image, you might want to reduce the first rows height...

Comment: Hi, first thanks for replying, your sample code was very useful, i've managed to get the text centered below the `ion-avatar` :) now my problem is this whole block (text + image) isn't centered inside `ion-col` edit: Adding justify-content-center did the trick with a col-auto to take all 12 columns ;)